# Add class to li with specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a class to a li with specific Id. I tried this:

```
function updateIndex(indexValue){
    $('li[id=' + indexValue + ']').addClass("selectedQuestion")

}
```

I am not able to access indexValue variable in the li selector.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do a string concatenation to use the value of the `indexValue` parameter:

```
$('li[id=' + indexValue + ']').addClass("selectedQuestion")
```

Or, given the attribute you are selecting by is an id:

```
$('li#' + indexValue).addClass("selectedQuestion");
```

Or, given that id is supposed to be unique you shouldn't need the 'li' part (unless your meaning is to select that element only if it has that id *and* is an li element):

```
$('#' + indexValue).addClass("selectedQuestion");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function updateIndex(index){
   $('li[id=' + index +']').addClass("selectedQuestion")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of yours. You have to **concatinate** the **indexValue** variable

```
function updateIndex(indexValue){
  $('li[id=' + indexValue + ']').addClass("selectedQuestion")

}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer briefly to make it clearer for other readers.